# The reason why we need a function prototype for methods that is imported from its header file

Tags: c, header-files, function-prototypes

I am currently studying about pointer from K&R.

In page, 109 the authors declare function prototypes for methods

```
int getline(char *, int);
char *alloc(int);
```

even after, the source file import their standard libraries in the beginning.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
```

isn't their declaration is done in their header file? What is the reason the authors declare the function prototypes of these methods when they are already declared in their own header files?

Comment: Stdio.h & stdlib.h don't declare your custom functions. They declare the functions provided by the standard library that comes with most C compilers.

Comment: I don't know the book, but no? Those aren't standard functions. Maybe they were back when it was written, but it *is* a very old book.

Comment: POSIX added a [getline()](https://linux.die.net/man/3/getline) function a few decades after that book was written, with a different prototype than that one. That might be giving you issues?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a getline function introduced around 2010 (long after the book was written) but it is not the same as the function you have mentioned. The library function's prototype is:

```
size_t getline (char ** __lineptr, size_t * __n, FILE * __stream) ;
```

Also there is no `alloc` in C. There are three similarly named library functions for memory allocation.

```
void *malloc(size_t n);
void *calloc(size_t n, size_t size
void *realloc(void *p, size_t size)
```

I believe you will find the above functions as part of library in K&R.

So K&R had to declare the prototypes of `getline` and `alloc` functions and implement them.